# Jaxb marshelling not working

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an abstract class **A** that has two implementation **A1** and **A2**. Three class has the Jaxb annotation needed to be marshalled (**XmlRootElement**,**XmllAccessor** ... ).

Class **B** has bidirectional one to many relation with **A**

```
@XmlElementRef
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="b");
List<A> As;
```

when i marshell B , the Abstract A i marshelled and not the concrete one , so the fields in A1 and A2 didn't marshelled.
i tried to annotate the List with **XmlElementRef** but **Invalid XmlElementRef on property data** is thrown stating that **Referenced Element not declared**.

I am using **Moxy**.